# Loop through Redux option framework repeater field

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, loop, array, theme-options

I am using Repeater field of Redux Framework in WordPress.
I have created the repeater field and assigned the data. Now I am trying to display those data in front end. But I am not getting how can I do it. Here is the array of the data:

```
Array
(
    [redux_repeater_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => 
                )

        )

    [home-feature-title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title 1
            [1] => Title 2
            [2] => Title 3
        )

    [home-feature-url] => Array
        (
            [0] => #
            [1] => #
            [2] => #
        )

    [home-feature-url-text] => Array
        (
            [0] => Visit Us
            [1] => Visit Us
            [2] => Visit Us
        )

    [home-feature-bgcolor] => Array
        (
            [0] => #d53f34
            [1] => #e5ac1b
            [2] => #34a3d5
        )

)
```

I don't want [redux_repeater_data] and I don't even know from where that's coming. I want to print **Title 1**, **#**, **Visit Us** and **color code** from the array but I don't know how can I do it.